# Open a WINDOWS PHONE app on click of a URL like www.myapp.com

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I want to open a **WINDOWS PHONE** app on click of a URL like www.myapp.com. If app is not installed it should open the link in a browser. Kindly help me whether it can be achieved or not.

Scenario - URL (www.myapp.com) will be sent through a mail. on click if app is installed it should open it otherwise it should be opened through a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this plugin

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

It does exactly what you need.

Happy coding!

EDIT:

The previous plugin doesn't work with windows phone, custom url scheme could be an approach to your needs

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

So you can lauch your app from another app or browser, but is depends on a custom scheme like yourapp://, not a normal url, so if the app is not installed, it will open the store instead a webpage. Maybe you can do a workarround with this

Comment: Thanks Del. Isn't it possible in WINDOWS app to redirect to a web page rather than opening the store?

Comment: I dont know, as I never worked with windows phone, in native looks posible, probably you need to code your own cordova plugin